# How to refer to variables which lie beyond causal pathway

Tags: causality, dag

Causal diagrams are extremely good tools for discussing research plans for multivariate modeling between statisticians and non-statisticians. It's easy after some deliberation to decide which variables should go into a model based on their classification as confounders, precision variables. At least this applies insofar as identifying additive models, I'm unsure what language/visualizations applied to identifying interactions graphically.

However, it's generally accepted that adjusting for variables which are *caused* by the outcome will bias the estimated causal relationship between the main effect and outcome of interest. For instance, if you're estimating links between smoking and obesity, researchers might consider adjusting for forced expiratory volume (don't ask me why... maybe because of it's relationship to exposure). However obese people might have less FEV because of the compressing effect of fat on the chest cavity and also lack of physical exercise. So FEV is causally determined by obesity. We show that FEV lies beyond the causal pathway.

Is there a term that refers to such variables?

Comment: Sometimes Pearl uses the term [Collider Bias](http://ftp.cs.ucla.edu/pub/stat_ser/r332.pdf) to refer to the example you give, but I'm not sure if that fits your bill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what comes to mind.

X exposure, C covariate, Y outcome.

X --> C <-- Y   This is the situation you describe, and you know that it's a collider in this case, and controlling for it will bias the X Y association.

X <-- C --> Y This of course is confounding, and C should be adjusted for to get an unbiased estimtate of the X Y association.

X --> Y --> C  I think this situation is also included in your question, but I don't know of any special term for C in this case, beyond the usual things like endogenous. I also don't think that controlling for C would result in any bias.

After all of that, I think the answer is no, there isn't a special term for that, but I disagree that controlling for a consequence of the outcome will neccessarily lead to bias (but it's also pointless, so you still shouldn't do it).

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of both X --> C <-- Y and X --> Y --> C, i.e. C may or may not be conditionally independent of X. I see now why adjusting for C in the non-collider example would not be biased for that reason, but would be a stupid idea because of possibly spurious correlation with X.

Comment: @D L Dahly nice clear answer. As a technical note, in your third case, if there is another covariate C2 that is a confounder of the X-Y relationship, then controlling for the original C can cause collider bias. This is probably not of practical importance, though, since if you are already adjusting for C2 in the analysis any potential collider bias is blocked; and if you aren't adjusting for C2 then the confounding is a concern regardless of whether you adjust for the original C or not. And in answer to the OP, C could be called a 'downstream consequence of Y'.